# different child view in expandable list view android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter, custom-adapter

Is it possible to add different child view XMLs in every row in expendable list view?

I have created a expendable list view using **custom adapter**
but I want to make it like the following

The expandable list view contains data gender (male and female)

If gender is male, when we click, the child view should show male menu

If gender is female, when we click, the child view should show female menu

how to achieve it?

here is my adapter code

```
 package com.example.expandlist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Group> groups;

    public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> groups) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
    }
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return chList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

    tv.setText(child.getName().toString());
    iv.setImageResource(child.getImage());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return chList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
    tv.setText(group.getName());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

You need to create two different XML layouts for Male and Female gender then in `getChildView` method:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (child.getGender==MALE){
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item_male, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        tv.setText(child.getName().toString());
        iv.setImageResource(child.getImage());
    }else{
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item_female, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        tv.setText(child.getName().toString());
        iv.setImageResource(child.getImage());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: thx dude, i need to modify a little bit from your answer... i`ll post my solution as soon as posible...